# Console window won't hide

Tags: c#

I need to stop then restart Windows Update Service but I want the console to close after or not showing at all. I tried everything it says here but the console window still won't go away itself.

```
  Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C start \"wuauserv\"";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Are you not just trying to start/stop the service rather than run the service process yourself?

Comment: Using the cmd shell for this is silly. Google for how to stop and start Windows services directly from C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id suggest instead of your [How to stop/Start windows services](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/)

> **Start service**
>
> The following method tries to start a service specified by a service name. Then it waits until the service is running or a timeout
>   occurs.
>
> ```
> public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
> {
>   ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
>   try
>   {
>     TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
>
>     service.Start();
>     service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
>   }
>   catch
>   {
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Stop service**
>
> The following method tries to stop the specified service and it waits until the service is stopped or a timeout occurs.
>
> ```
> public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
> {
>   ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
>   try
>   {
>     TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
>
>     service.Stop();
>     service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
>   }
>   catch
>   {
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```

You can then control the service without any console window appearing

Comment: I don't see any downvote? neither see a reason for that.

Comment: @BugFinder, One reason for downvote would be the link only answer.

Comment: It was a short page - copy and pasting data from it would seem excessive.. but I guess that could be an answer

Comment: @BugFinder, I did it for you.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Don't know why tried everything from the approach of process but it didn't work.

Comment: Your original command line wouldnt have exited because you didnt start the service with 'net start wuauserve' it just ran the exe... Which probably eouldnt exit because it was checking for updates and waiting to poll for the next check etc

Answer (score 0):

Along with `RedirectStandardOutput` set `RedirectStandardError` to `true` as well

```
process.startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Also make sure that `UseShellExecute` must be set to `false` else there is no point in setting `CreateNoWindow = true`.